# CSS Media Query IPhone has a Margin anyone know how to clear so site has 100% width?

Tags: media-queries

Hi Im building a responsive site with media queries and Im having problems with the smart phone. When previewed there seems to be a 30px border left and right. I have tried to 0px & 0% all margin and padding but it wont go away. Please see screen shot here

http://optimise-website-marketing.com/wp-content/themes/bones/images/photo.PNG

heres the site:

http://optimise-website-marketing.com/

Im using the following media queries:

/* iPhone [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

Any help much appreciated :-)

Im waiting so much time pulling my hair out here, please can anyone shed some light on whats happening?

Matt

Comment: Im also using the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

Is this where the problem lies...Please help :-) anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Line 1083 is the problem:

```
.page {
    padding: 0 20px;
} /* general article on a page style */
```